# Hibernate Envers throwing java.sql.SQLException: Fail to convert to internal representation

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers, nhibernate-envers

I am using the hibernate envers version **5.2.17.Final** to store and retrieve the audit history for the entities and getting the following exception while retrieving the audit history for a `Category` entity.

Here is how my `Category` entity looks like this. As you can see NCRRule is mapped to Category with the **NAME** rather then the primary key **Id**.

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = TableNames.CATEGORY)
@Audited
@AuditTable(value = TableNames.CATEGORY_HISTORY)
public class Category {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "categoryGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "categoryGenerator", sequenceName = "GENERAL_CATEGORY_SQ", allocationSize = 1)
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "NCR_RULE", insertable = false, updatable = false, referencedColumnName = "NAME")
    @Getter(onMethod = @__({@JsonIgnore, @Transient}))
    @Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED)
    private NCRRule ncrRule;
}
```

`NCRRule` is the entity, which is not audited

```
@Entity
@Table(name= TableNames.NCR_RULE)
public class NCRRule implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "NAME", unique = true)
    private String ncrRuleName;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getNcrRuleName() {
        return ncrRuleName;
    }
}
```

Exception Stacktrace is below:

```
2019-02-05 18:14:08 [http-nio-0.0.0.0-8899-exec-2] ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/risk-portal] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query] with root cause
java.sql.SQLException: Fail to convert to internal representation
at oracle.jdbc.driver.CharCommonAccessor.getLong(CharCommonAccessor.java:258)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CVarcharAccessor.getLong(T4CVarcharAccessor.java:562)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.GeneratedStatement.getLong(GeneratedStatement.java:228)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.GeneratedScrollableResultSet.getLong(GeneratedScrollableResultSet.java:620)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.GeneratedResultSet.getLong(GeneratedResultSet.java:1361)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyResultSet.getLong(HikariProxyResultSet.java)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BigIntTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(BigIntTypeDescriptor.java:63)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:261)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:257)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:247)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:333)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2868)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1747)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1673)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1562)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:732)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:991)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:949)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:341)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2692)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2675)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2507)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2502)
at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:502)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:392)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:216)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1490)
at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1445)
at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1414)
at org.hibernate.envers.query.internal.impl.AbstractAuditQuery.buildAndExecuteQuery(AbstractAuditQuery.java:101)
at org.hibernate.envers.query.internal.impl.RevisionsOfEntityQuery.list(RevisionsOfEntityQuery.java:120)
at org.hibernate.envers.query.internal.impl.AbstractAuditQuery.getResultList(AbstractAuditQuery.java:107)
at com.lch.grouprisk.riskportal.audit.query.AuditQueryUtils.getAuditQueryResults(AuditQueryUtils.java:34)
at com.lch.grouprisk.riskportal.audit.query.AuditQueryUtils.getHistories(AuditQueryUtils.java:55)
at audit.AuditHistoryRepositoryImpl.findByEntityId(AuditHistoryRepositoryImpl.java:20)
```

I tried setting the `@AuditMappedBy(mappedBy = "ncrRuleName")` to the `private NCRRule ncrRule;` in `Category` entity, but I get exception at startup.

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: @AuditMappedBy points to a property that doesn't exist: NCRRule.ncrRuleName
```

Code to retrieve the audit history is:

```
        AuditQuery auditQuery = auditReader.createQuery()
            .forRevisionsOfEntity(Category.class, false, true)
            .add(AuditEntity.id().eq(entityId))
            .addOrder(AuditEntity.revisionProperty("timestamp").asc());

        List<AuditQueryResult<Category>> auditQueryResults = AuditQueryUtils.getAuditQueryResults(auditQuery, Category.class);
```

Comment: Hibernate can only link to the primary key and not a surrogate key. That is making hibernate confused and trying to convert a string to a long.

Comment: Hi Augusto, the problem is not with the hibernate storing or retrieving the data, that works fine. It is the `envers`, which is causing the problem and trying to convert the string to a long.

Comment: I tested your scenario based on the details you provided against H2 and I could not replicate the issue so either this is Oracle specific or there is something you haven't included that is influencing your issue.  Are you able to test against another platform such as H2 to see if you run into the same problem?  If not, could you open a JIRA issue and attach a runnable test case that replicates the problem you have?

Comment: Hi @Naros, this looks same issue, isn’t it? https://hibernate.atlassian.net/plugins/servlet/mobile?originPath=%2Fbrowse%2FHHH-8066#issue/HHH-8066

Comment: It could be; could you use our templates at https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-test-case-templates and construct an ORM5 test case with your mappings that fails in your environment?  You can attach it to that jira and ping me on it; that will certainly help if it is.